# Is such kind of manifold Riemannian? Deforming the metric on the unit square by a weight applied in one direction

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If the metric is defined on a bounded subset of the x-y plane,let's say a closed square area $0\le x,y\le1 $, the metric is defined as $$\langle u,v\rangle =\langle (u_x,u_y),(v_x,v_y)\rangle =\langle u_x,v_x\rangle +w\langle u_y,v_y\rangle $$ where $u_x,u_y$ are the components of the tangent vector in $x,y$ directions respectively,$w$ is a weighting factor. For the case $w\rightarrow\infty$, is the manifold defined by such a metric Riemannian?

My question is: if it's a Riemannian manifold, then it should have a finite diameter since $0\le x,y\le1$ is compact. But obviously there are points with an infinite distance between them, for example the point pair $[(0.1,0.1),(0.5,0.5)]$ . Something wrong with my configuration? Or it's a kind of degenerated structure?

Comment: What does "In the case $w \to \infty$" even mean? What's the inner product of $(1,1)$ and itself (based at $(1/3,1/3)$, say?

Comment: I know it's wired. But at least when $w$ is finite, we have a meaningful definition. Do you suggest that it's meaningless when a smooth metric change will lead to a meaningless result? Or we just result in a union of sub-manifolds (the line segments in x direction)? So it's not a valid definition of metric?

Comment: I can't tell what you're saying. The point is that if you can't tell me what the inner product of two vectors is, you haven't defined a metric.

Comment: OK. I think I am still struggling with the diameter thing. If $w$ is finite, then we do have a valid Riemannian manifold, but it can have an arbitrary large diameter if $w$ is big enough. I was wondering why in my last $SU(2^n)$ based configuration similar to this one, even for an arbitrary large $w$ there are results to show the diameter has an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to consider a family of Riemannian manifolds $M_w$ with the weight factor $w$, and investigate their limit as $w\to\infty$ (usually, with respect to some form of the Gromov-Hausdorff metric, but there are other options too). The limit may be an interesting object, or not: depends on how you deform the metric with $w$.

In the case you described, the space  $M_w$ is a  rectangle of size $1\times w$. These don't converge as $\omega\to\infty$ in the standard   GH sense, but they do converge in the [pointed GH sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence#Pointed_Gromov.E2.80.93Hausdorff_convergence). The limit is an infinite strip, $[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$.

There is a better known construction of this kind: approximation of a [sub-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_manifold) with Riemannian manifolds. The principle is the same: tangent vectors in certain directions ("horizontal" subbundle of the tangent bundle) are given their Euclidean length, the other directions are penalized by a large factor $w$. The difference is that in the sub-Riemannian case, the horizontal subbundle is rich enough so that any two points can be connected by a curve tangent to it. Therefore, for any two fixed points $p,q$ the distance $d_w(p,q)$ has a finite limit as $w\to\infty$; namely the shortest length of a "horizontal" curve connection $p$ to $q$.

In your case, the "horizontal" vectors are *literally* horizontal, and as you observed, one cannot connect two arbitrary points moving in the horizontal direction.